# Sweet Egyptian bread?

Tags: food-and-drink, egypt

Not sure if this belongs here.

I was in Egypt a few years ago, in Hurghada. I remember I used to eat this sweet, white naan-bread style bread.

I remember that it was dry and broke into your hands easily.

Could you help me find the name of this bread?

Aish Merahrah isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your description I can tell it is **Feteer Meshaltet**.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea where can I get it outside Egypt? Making it yourself is hard, as I read.

Comment: @claudio where exactly outside Egypt?

Comment: In Europe (Finland) or online (with shipping to Finland)